# Method Rotate doesn't work correct in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using the method Rotate from

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations;
```

To rotate UIElement

But this method doesn't work as it should. Rotates the element, but change the height and width.
My xaml Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" 
            Content="Click"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ScrollViewer Height="150" 
                  Width="200" 
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image x:Name="myImage" 
            Source="/Images/TestImage.png" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Turn method:

```
int Pos = 0;

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pos = --Pos;

        await myImage.Rotate(duration: 0, delay: 1, 
            centerX: (float)myImage.ActualWidth / 2,
                centerY: (float)myImage.ActualHeight / 2,
                value: Pos * 90).StartAsync();
    }
```

And part of the UIElement is not displayed (clipped) and because of this it is not possible to do scrolling over the whole element.

[image: Normal position]

[image: VerticalScroll]

How can you rotate an element so that its dimensions change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only found one way to solve this problem, and that was to put in a Grid-bung.

```
    <ScrollViewer Height="150" 
                  Width="200" 
                  x:Name="myScrollViewer"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel x:Name="mainContext" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid x:Name="BungTop" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="100" Width="100" />
                <Image x:Name="myImage" 
                        Source="/Images/TestImage.png" />
                <Grid x:Name="BungBotton" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="100" Width="100"/>
            </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>
```

They can turn visibility on or off, or resize.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a image into a `ScrollViewer` control, the image will not be shown completely because there is enough inner space in a `ScrollViewer`. And the `Height` and `Width` property of the `ScrollViewer` is already set, the actual size of the rotated image  won’t exceed the `Height` and `Width` property of the `ScrollViewer`. Therefore, the dimensions of the image won’t change when you rotate it.

If you want to rotate your image so that its dimensions change, please do not use `ScrollViewer`, set the `Height` and `Width` property of the image directly, like this:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage"  Height="150" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Source="Assets/TestImage.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

Comment: The fact is that in the ScrollViewer I have an element that the user can increase and decrease, and I need the ScrollViewer so that the user can scrolling the object

Comment: The size of `ScrollViewer.Content`(here is the image) is determined after the `ScrollViewer` control loads a image. When you rotate your image, part of the image will be clipped because the rotated image’s width exceeds the height of `ScrollViewer.Content`. You could try to rotate the `ScrollViewer` control instead of rotating the image. Or, you could set the values of `Width` property and `Height` property of the image to be the same.